# React Native:state update did not trigger re-render

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

My RN 0.62.2 app upload images and display them. The image is stored in a state array. The new image gets added at the end of array when there is a new image uploaded. Here is the method to add images:

```
  const [imgs, setImgs] = useState();
  const addImages = (pics) => {
    if (!pics || pics===[] || pics==={}) return;
    let temp = imgs, updated=false;
    if (imgs && imgs!==[] && imgs!=={}) {
        let names = imgs.map(item => item.fileName);
        for(let i=0;i<pics.length;i++) {
            if (!names.includes(pics[i].fileName)) {
                temp.push(pics[i]);
                updated = true;
            };
        };
        if (updated) setImgs(temp); //<<== add more images to the array and reset the state
    } else {
        setImgs(pics);  //<<==for initial upload of images
    };
```

The image array is display within a component:

```
 return (
       <MyAccordion title={"Image"} absPosition={false} initOpen={accordImgOpen} screenSize={{width:screen_width, height:((imgs && imgs.length>9) ? screen_width+(screen_width/3)*(Math.ceil(((imgs.length-9)%3)/3)):screen_width)}} >                      
             <DisplayImages pics={imgs} deleteImage={deleteImage} />  //<<==here imgs is a state and the images array is display in grids
        </MyAccordion>
 )
```

The code was working fine until today. Now the added image was not presented by function component `DisplayImages` right after. I need to do things such as open Modal and close it to trigger the re-rendering. On console output shows the state `imgs` is updated. What could prevent the page from rerendering after state is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have not clone the imgs. Try this

```
const [imgs, setImgs] = useState();
  const addImages = (pics) => {
    if (!pics || pics===[] || pics==={}) return;
    let temp = [...imgs], updated=false;
    if (imgs && imgs!==[] && imgs!=={}) {
        let names = imgs.map(item => item.fileName);
        for(let i=0;i<pics.length;i++) {
            if (!names.includes(pics[i].fileName)) {
                temp.push(pics[i]);
                updated = true;
            };
        };
        if (updated) setImgs(temp); //<<== add more images to the array and reset the state
    } else {
        setImgs(pics);  //<<==for initial upload of images
    };
```